# visual studio C# combo box event

Tags: c#, events, combobox, selectedindexchanged

```
   private void droplesson_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Equals("LESSON1"));
        reload("LESSON1.txt");
        if(e.Equals("LESSSON2"));
        reload("LESSON2.txt");
        if(e.Equals("LESSON3"));
        reload("LESSON3.txt");
        if(e.Equals("LESSON4"));
        reload("LESSON4.txt");
        if (e.Equals("LESSON5"));
        reload("LESSON5.txt");

    }
```

Above code is not working. I want to change the dropdown menu such that when i select the particular lesson it reload that lesson.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybX5h.jpg)

Comment: Saying 'not working' is never enough, details are required. But also - your code is not clear - you are putting ';' at the end of each 'if' statement - so everything gets reloaded...

Comment: yes, the last statement is only executing i.e LESSON5 is only loading

Answer (score 0):

You added ';' at the end of every line, including the 'if' lines, soo all of the 'reload' calls got executed...

This is how your code should look:

```
private void droplesson_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Equals("LESSON1"))
        reload("LESSON1.txt");
    if(e.Equals("LESSSON2"))
        reload("LESSON2.txt");
    if(e.Equals("LESSON3"))
        reload("LESSON3.txt");
    if(e.Equals("LESSON4"))
        reload("LESSON4.txt");
    if (e.Equals("LESSON5"))
        reload("LESSON5.txt");
}
```

Comment: then, how to reload only one statement

Comment: The code I gave above executes one statement, according to the value of 'e'. What is it that is still unclear?

Comment: I want the code such that when selecting an item in drop down menu, it will change the respective text in the main box.

Comment: Well, I am not going to write that code for you... I pointed out the logical problem in the code you have posted, I do not know what 'reload' does, and I leave this to you. The code you have posted causes all 5 'reload' calls to be executed always, and  reload("LESSON5.txt") always executes last. I fixed it for you so 'reload' executes according to the value of 'e'. If you have another question, on another code, post it.